# How to import the functions written in a file in the same folder in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file named features.py, which are the definitions of functions. The file is in the current folder and I want to import the functions from it. I tried `import features` but when I try to use my function such as features.plus(1,4), it tips that `name 'plus' is not defined`. So how can I import my functions from the file in right way ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from .file import YourClass
```

or this:

```
from .file import function1,function2
```

also you can do this:

```
from .file import *
```

Answer (score 0):

If your directory name is dir then you should do as follows

```
from .dir import features
```

The above will import the entire `features` module. If you want to import only the `plus` function, use

```
from .dir import features.plus
```